# Angular Fire - forEach in controller

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I want to iterate by all items received from Firebase in controller, but I can't - console.log(item) nothing display.

My code:

```
var URL = "https://project.firebaseio.com/link";    
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
$scope.link = $firebaseArray(ref);

$scope.link.$loaded().then(function(list){
    console.info(list);
    list.forEach(function(item){
        console.log("1");
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```

In console.info(list) I can see 2 opbejcts from FB and "$ functions", but list.forEach do nothing (also console.log("1") doesn't display).

If I use in view "link" variable I can use in ng-repeat.

I've tested with angular.forEach, but it doesn't work too.

```
var URL = "https://project.firebaseio.com/link";    
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
$scope.link = $firebaseArray(ref);

$scope.link.$loaded().then(function(list){
    console.info(list);
    angular.forEach(list, function(item){
        console.log("1");
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```

Comment: console.info(typeof list); if it's not an array, that's your problem.

Comment: I've upgrade Angular to 1.3 version and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the array you have:

```
var URL = "https://project.firebaseio.com/link";    
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
$scope.link = $firebaseArray(ref);

$scope.link.$loaded().then(function(list){
    angular.forEach($scope.link, function(item){
        console.log("1");
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```